# Swap values of two columns of two tables

Tags: sql-server

There are two tables `T1` and `T2` having columns like `Id` and `Name`.

How to swap `name` column values of both the tables on the basis of `Id`?

[image]

Comment: what about just change the name of table

Comment: @Shashi if Wanderer solution is working, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

- Create temp table with same schema as T1
- populate it with T1 values
- update T1 with T2 values
- update T2 with temp table values
- drop temp table

Sample code:

```
SELECT Id, Name INTO #tt FROM T1

UPDATE T1
SET T1.Name = T2.Name
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id

UPDATE T2
SET T2.Name = #tt.Name
FROM T2 INNER JOIN #tt ON T2.Id = #tt.Id

DROP TABLE #tt
```

Just to be sure you could also add some error checking or transaction to avoid catastrophic results

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a temporary column in `T1`, called `tempName`.
2. Copy names of `T2` into `tempName` of `T1` with corresponding `id`.

   ```
   update T1
   set tempName = (
       select name
       from T2
       where T1.id = T2.id
   );
   ```
3. Copy names of `T1` into `T2` with corresponding `id`:

   ```
   update T2
   set name = (
       select name
       from T1
       where T1.id = T2.id
   );
   ```
4. Copy the values of `tempName` to `name` in `T1`:

   ```
    update T1
    set name = tempName;
   ```
5. `Drop` `tempName` from `T1`;

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table with the values as same as the table `T1` values. Then update the `name` column of table `T1` with `name` column value of table `T2`. Then update the `name` column of table `T2` with `name` column value of the temp table. After updating both the tables, drop the temp table.

**Query**

```
-- create temp table
select * into #temp from [T1];

-- update table T1
update t1
set t1.[Name] = t2.[Name]
from [T1] t1
join [T2] t2
on t1.[Id] = t2.[Id];

-- update table T2
update t1
set t1.[Name] = t2.[Name]
from [T2] t1
join #temp t2
on t1.[Id] = t2.[Id];

-- dop temp table
drop table #temp;

-- check both the tables
select * from [T1];
select * from [T2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```sql
SELECT * INTO #T1 FROM T1     

UPDATE T1 SET T1.NAME = T2.NAME FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID

UPDATE T2 SET T2.NAME = #T1.NAME  FROM T2 INNER JOIN #T1 ON T2.ID = #T1.ID

DROP TABLE #T1 --Drop temp table Table
select * from T1
select * from T2
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**